# How to construct an executable jar with JavaFX dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar, javafx, executable-jar

I am building an application with JavaFX and I work with maven. I want to be able to make a jar file for the end user with the JavaFX dependencies included, so that the end-user doesn't have to install JavaFX to run the excutable.

Can someone tell how to do this?

Comment: ref :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592123/can-i-run-a-jar-file-without-jdk

Comment: But these links say nothing about JavaFX dependencies? The executable should not require any dependencies like JavaFX installed on the end-user computer to run.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Daniel Zwolenski's blog](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/)

He shows how to build a Maven wrapper around the javafxpackager tool; this includes building "self-contained applications" that include the JRE (and JavaFX) as part of a native executable application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like JSmooth or Launch4j to create such executables. The jfxrt and other dependencies can be added in classpath in any of those tools.